# How to include libraries which both depend on the same library?

Tags: android, android-library

My project depends on two libraries, one is `ActionBarSherlock` and the other is the `Facebook SDK`.

Both of these library projects depend on the `android-support-library`.

The problem is now, if I include this library in both library projects, I´m getting this build error

```
Android Dex: [MyApp] Unable to execute DX
Android Dex: [MyApp] com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter;
```

How can I manage to let both libraries depend on the same library?

Comment: you mean you change the java build path?

Comment: I didn´t change any build path, I just included those libs which both include the same other lib

Comment: i came up with the same situation a month ago for V7_support lib and Facebook. What i did is i removed v4 from facebook and added v7 as a library into facebook. This solved my problem. Hope this will help you.

Comment: check wether u refering same library or not. if u refering same library means it wont cause any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually shows up when you have two different versions of the jar file in your app. Just make sure to include the same jar in both your libraries, and the jar will only be included once in the APK.

Comment: How did you check they were the same version?

Comment: Okay my fault. Now I added the library to the main project too and it works, thank you

Answer (score 1):

TO overcome this problem solution is you must have same support library in your all library and main project for that you need to select every project and add support lib as bellow

Right click project
Android tools 
Add support library

Repit for all projects done!!

Answer (score 0):

include the `android support library` in the `ActionBarSherlock` lib, and then include the `ActionBarSherlock` library in the `Facebook` library , and finally include the `Facebook` library into your `project.`

***At Last : Clean your project***

Comment: I think nesting libs is not the best solution. I solved it now by adding the same support library to all libraries and the main project. thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Right click on the Project Name
2.  Select Build Path -> Configure Build Path
3.   In Java Build Path, go to the tab Order and Export

4.  Unchecked your .jar library
```

hope so it help you....:)

Answer (score 0):

Well I had the same problem. I solved it by doing this-
1- go to the libs directory of your project. There would be android support library's jar file which would be from Google. Delete this jar.
2- Copy the android support library jar from Facebook SDK's lib directory.
3- Paste this jar in libs directory in your project(the same place where you have deleted the jar provided by Google in step 1).
4- Now right click on this jar. Select 'Build path'. Select 'Add to build path'

You are done.
Now you have the same JAR file, which is provided packaged in the Facebook SDK at all places.

Note: Copying in the reverse way i.e. copying the Google provided support jar into Facebook SDK did not work for me. It was not able to get LocalBroadcastManager. I do not know why.